# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, concurrentmodification

I was trying the following code **Java 8 SE**
I ran it directly from eclipse, it has the below-mentioned exception also I
ran it with command prompt it produces the same result.

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
test.add("A");
test.add("B");
test.add("c");
test = test.subList(0, 2);
Stream<String> s = test.stream();
test.add("d");
s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

I am not sure as to why exactly it gives the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1388)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
```

Java version I am running with

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: `ArrayList` stream uses `ArrayListSpliterator` which is `fail-fast`, you've created a stream and modifying the underlying collection

Comment: @nullpointer this is happening because of `subList`

Comment: This is probably a bug in Java-8 which is fixed in Java-9. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924360/1746118) with further details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Minimal Code

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("java-8", "subList", "bug")).subList(0, 2);
Stream<String> stream = test.stream();
test.add("java-9");
stream.forEach(System.out::println); // any terminal operation
```

#### Java-8 [Bug]

The code above executed with Java-8 throws a CME. According to the [javadoc of `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   `ConcurrentModificationException`.
>
> Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

*Output*:

> ```
> java-8
> subList
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
> ```

#### Question

Under the [similar guidelines,](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8136821) modifying a collection while it's being iterated is considered to be a programming error and consequently throwing of `ConcurrentModificationException` is performed on a "best-effort" basis.

But then the question was, in the code above did we actually end up modifying the collection while it was being iterated or rather before that?

<sub>shouldn't stream be lazy?</sub>

On searching further for such expected behavior, found something similar reported and fixed as a bug -  [ArrayList.subList().spliterator() is not late-binding](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8148748) and this has been fixed with Java-9.

Another bug related to this - [ArrayList.subList().iterator().forEachRemaining() off-by-one-error](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8169679)

#### Java-11 [Fixed]

Though fixed in Java-9 according to the bug report, the actual test that I was performing was on the LTS version and the code as shared above works without any exception.

*Output*:

> ```
> java-8
> subList
> java-9
> ```

Answer (score 5):

This is because of `subList`,let me explain with different scenarios

**From java docs** [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference)

> For well-behaved stream sources, the source can be modified before the terminal operation commences and those modifications will be reflected in the covered elements.
>
> Except for the escape-hatch operations iterator() and spliterator(), execution begins when the terminal operation is invoked, and ends when the terminal operation completes.

**Case 1:** Successful (because the source can be modified before the terminal operation commences)

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("A");
    test.add("B");
    test.add("c");
    //test = test.subList(0, 2);
    Stream s = test.stream();
    test.add("d");
    s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output :**

```
A
B
c
d
```

**Case 2:** Failed for `sublist` different reference

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("A");
    test.add("B");
    test.add("c");
    List<String> test1 = test.subList(0, 2);
    Stream s = test1.stream();
    test1.add("d");
    s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output :**

```
A
BException in thread "main" 
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at 
java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1388)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at com.demo.Example.Main2.main(Main2.java:30)
```

**case 3:** Failed for `sublist` same reference, Both lists are different

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("A");
    test.add("B");
    test.add("c");
    System.out.println(test.hashCode()); //94401
    test = test.subList(0, 2);
    System.out.println(test.hashCode()); //3042
    Stream s = test.stream();
    test.add("d");
    s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output :**

```
94401
3042
A
B
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at 
java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1388)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at com.demo.Example.Main2.main(Main2.java:32)
```

**Final Conclusion**

> > The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield **incorrect results.**)

**From docs subList** [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)

Comment: my system `java version "1.8.0_171"`

Comment: Yes you are correct about the output , I am also not convinced about the output and why the sublist behave in that way. It would be great to know the actual reason.

Comment: For the following code on removing the stream there is no error `List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
  test.add("A");
  test.add("B");
  test.add("c");
  test = test.subList(0, 2);
 
  test.add("d");

  System.out.println(test);` It seems the sublist is now okay it confuses me.

Comment: Yes because you are not streaming sublist right, the problem here is stream sublist and then modify @Joydeep

Comment: Ahh so while we create a stream of the sublist if the original list is modified then CME .... I hope I got it correct !

Comment: This is probably a bug in Java-8 which is fixed in Java-9. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924360/1746118) with further details.

Answer (score 3):

One way to get this exception is by updating the underlying list after creating a stream from it, which is what happened here.

Just perform all your `add` calls before calling `stream()`, and you should be fine:

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
test.add("A");
test.add("B");
test.add("c");
test.add("d"); // Moved here
test = test.subList(0, 2);
Stream s = test.stream();
// test.add("d") removed here
s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you modify the content of the ArrayList while stream is in use (not closed).

```
    Stream s = test.stream();
    test.add("d"); <<<- here
    s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

As javadoc of ConcurrentModificationException mentions:

> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a
>       Collection while another thread is iterating over it.

This is true for the streams as well, as in simple case they are based on iterators.

Additionally,

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been 
>       concurrently modified by a different thread.